# Given a string, and an array of strings check if string contains all words in the array

Tags: php

So here is situation let's imagine a string and an array:

```
$str = 'Sample string';
$arr = array('sample', 'string')
```

What would be the best way to determine if the given string has all of the words contained in the array? String can be longer, and has additional words, it does not matter. The only thing I need, is a function that given a string and an array would return true, if string contains every single word that is in array (case and order I'm which they appear does not matter)

Comment: Split the string into an array of words using str_word_count(), array_walk that array forcing lowercase, then use array_intersect()

Comment: Please avoid posting solutions as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `str_word_count` with extra parameter `1` like as

```
$str = 'Sample string';
$arr = array('sample', 'string');
$new_arr = array_intersect(array_map('strtolower',str_word_count($str,1)),$arr);
print_r($new_arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => sample
    [1] => string
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/447702)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
$strArray = explode(" ", $str);
$result = array_intersect($strArray, $arr);
if(sizeof($result) == sizeof($arr)){
   return TRUE;
}else{
   return FALSE;
}
```

if this don't work, then try swapping the inputs in `array_intersect($arr, $strArray)`
You can add other functions to make all lowercase before comparing to give it a finishing touch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php 
$words = array('sample', 'string');
$str = 'sample string';
strtolower($str);
$strArr = explode(' ',$str);
$wordfound = false;
foreach ($strArr as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($v,$words)) {$wordfound = true; break;}
    foreach($words as $kb => $vb) {
        if (strstr($v, $kb)) $wordfound = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($wordfound) {
    echo 'Found!';
}
else echo 'Not found!';
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance matters, I would use an associative array:

```
$words = array_flip(preg_split('/\\s+/', strtolower($str)));
$result = true;
foreach ($arr as $find) {
    if (!isset($words[$find])) {
        $result = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/447708)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Sample string';
$str1=strtolower($str);


 $arr = array(
            'sample',
            'string'
        );

        foreach($arr as $val)
        {
            if(strpos($str1,strtolower($val)) !== false)
            {
                $msg='true';
            }
            else
            {
                $msg='false';
                break;
            }
        }

     echo $msg;
```